# Javascript fade-in out with hovering the image

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have a this script.

On hover, this changes the image but how can I add fade out/in to this code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#first_01").hover(function() {
    $(".plan-select-01").find("img").attr("src", "https://example.com/img-1.png")
  }, function() {
    $('.plan-select-01').find("img").attr("src", "https://example.com/img-2.png")
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="plan-select-01">
  <section>
    <img src="https://example.com/image-1.png" alt="" />
    <div class="plan-hover">
      <li id="first_01">hover the image</li>
    </div>
  </section>
</li>
```

Comment: If not on hover, when did you want it to fade out/in?

Comment: You'd need more than one image loaded and then cross fade